# Scatter plot line to out of order data

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, line-plot

I am tracking the movements of an avian animal. I have detection points on an xy plot. I want to connect the previous detected point to the next detection, regardless of direction. This will assist with removing extraneous detections.

**Data Sample:**

[Sample input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLY1t.png)
The goal is to have a line from the previous data point to the next point.

[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytFki.png)

**Unsuccessful method 1:**

```
plt.figure('Frame',figsize=(16,12))
plt.imshow(frame)
plt.plot(x, y, '-ro', 'd',markersize=2.5, color='orange')
```

[Method 1 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LtdM.png)

**Unsuccessful method 2:**

```
plt.plot(np.sort(x), y[np.argsort(x)], '-bo', ms = 2)
```

[Method 2 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmbrT.png)

Comment: Can you describe a sample output please? For example can you give a sample data input, and an example of how you want the data to look with that data?

Comment: @chadmc I added the sample input and output above.

Comment: Sorry I meant it would help if you print your data in a python form.

Comment: It's clear from Method 1 output that you are passing far more data points to `plot` than you have in the sample input. I'm not sure but I think method 1 works. What happens if you try it with x and y coming from your sample input?

Comment: I ran the code again with fewer points and better filtering. Looks like it was an error on my end with the poor filtering of extraneous points. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used your sample data and make a plot with method 1 (but with pandas) and the output was as you expected. I don't understand why you have an unsuccessful result.

```py
data = [{'frame': 1, 'x': 5, 'y': 15},
 {'frame': 4, 'x': 10, 'y': 15},
 {'frame': 5, 'x': 15, 'y': 15},
 {'frame': 6, 'x': 20, 'y': 15},
 {'frame': 7, 'x': 23, 'y': 20},
 {'frame': 8, 'x': 25, 'y': 25},
 {'frame': 11, 'x': 20, 'y': 23},
 {'frame': 15, 'x': 15, 'y': 20},
 {'frame': 18, 'x': 8, 'y': 18},
 {'frame': 19, 'x': 8, 'y': 10},
 {'frame': 20, 'x': 12, 'y': 7}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data).sort_values('frame')
df.plot(x='x', y='y')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It was an error in my filtering that caused the image issue.